# TextView text not showing in ViewPager, while EditText is showing

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a layout with `TextView`, `EditText` and a `ListView`(less relevant):
`business_detail_screen.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Details"
    android:id="@+id/business_details_caption_label"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Address: "
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/business_address_label"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/business_address_edit_text"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Available : "
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/vacant_places_label"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/vacant_places_data"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/waiting_list_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

My main activity has a viewpager:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.enqme.enqu.BusinessActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:divider="@drawable/layout_divider"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ListView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/businesses_list_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/details_pager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and in my code i created a `PagerAdapter` which I deliver to `ViewPager`:

```
package com.enqme.enqu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.enqme.enqlib.utils.BackendApi;
import com.enqme.enqlib.utils.BackendCallback;
import com.enqme.enqlib.utils.Business;
import com.enqme.enqlib.utils.LogTags;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;


public class BusinessActivity extends Activity {
    private ViewPager businessDetailsPager;
    private BusinessDetailsPagerAdapter businessDetailsAdapter;

    private class BusinessDetailsPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Business> data;
    private Context context;

    public BusinessDetailsPagerAdapter(ArrayList<Business> d, Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
        data = d;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        int id = 0;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                id = R.layout.business_detail_screen_0;
                break;
            case 1:
                id = R.layout.business_detail_screen_1;
                break;
        }
        //LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(id, container, false);
        container.addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_business);
    currentBusiness = 0;
    businessDetailsPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.details_pager);
    businessDetailsAdapter = new BusinessDetailsPagerAdapter(businesses, this);
    businessDetailsPager.setAdapter(businessDetailsAdapter);
    }
}
```

The `ViewPager` shows but the problem is that only the `EditText` is shown, `TextView` is not shown at all, no text. If I set text to `EditText` field it is seen, so it is not an inflater problem.

Please Help:)

Comment: Try by removing the "text Appereance" from the XML and then run the code for now

Comment: i think it happen bcos of your  ListView it have android:layout_height="match_parent" so it cover full screen

Comment: I just copied and pasted your XML file it is  working fine on my system
Try to clean your project for now maybe it can help.

Comment: Already cleaned and rebuilt, no change. Looks the same also on another device.

Comment: ok, you are correct. as a standalone this works as expected, though, in context of my application this may be different. I will find why and post

Answer (score 0):

This happened because in the AndroidManifest.xml I had

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SigninActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BusinessActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>
</application>
```

and specifically 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

which caused black background, which I patched with
    android:background="#ffffff" 
in main activity. which caused the TextViews not to be visible - the background is still black and the text is black and I turn the background to white - no text (a lousy explanation)